# When did Visual Studio replace $PROJECT.filters with $PROJECT.vcxproj.filters?

Tags: visual-studio

I've recently noticed some $NAME.vcxproj files in our repo which have accompanying $NAME.filters files (Some, but not all, have $NAME.vcxproj.filters files too.) These filter files are not updated when new files are added/removed to the project, and Visual Studio doesn't seem to interact with them in any way.

I suspect they were created by an earlier version of Visual Studio, and that a subsequent version upgrade changed the default to .vcxproj.filters and started ignoring the old filter files. But I can't tell when this happened.

Which version of Visual Studio was the last one to generate/interact with $NAME.filters files? Did any version work with both these and the newer .vcxproj.filters files?

Comment: It has been .vcxproj.filters at least since VS2012 that I can verify, probably VS2010.  VS2008 and earlier did not use "vcxproj" yet.  Look through source control history, some odds you'll find old .vcproj files from which the .vcxproj file was generated when the project was upgraded.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll have a look. I can definitely say that there are no .vcproj files in the current repo, except for a few that came with third-party code (and seem all to have .vcxproj replacements in the same folder.)